# join channel failed DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KEY

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am trying to use Agora.io live video system. But i am getting the following errors in developer console.

After clicking the join button i got the following error.

```
Agora-SDK [ERROR]: [713FF] Get server node failed [DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KEY] https://webrtc2-ap-web-1.agora.io/api/v1 DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KEY agora.js:161:41
Agora-SDK [INFO]: [713FF] Join failed: DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KEY agora.js:155:41
[ERROR] : join channel failed DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KEY live:1146:15
```

I have to make an arrangement on the agora management panel. What am I doing wrong.

```
 var rand = <?php echo rand(1111111,9999999); ?>;
 var agoraAppId = 'API ID HERE'; // set app id
 var channelName = "stream_<?php echo $creatorUserID;?>_"+rand; // set channel name
// join a channel
function joinChannel() {
  var token = generateToken();
  var userID = 0; // set to null to auto generate uid on successfull connection

  // set the role
  client.setClientRole('host', function() {
    console.log('Client role set as host.');
  }, function(e) {
    console.log('setClientRole failed', e);
  });

  // client.join(token, 'allThingsRTCLiveStream', 0, function(uid) {
  client.join(token, channelName, userID, function(uid) {
      createCameraStream(uid, {});
      localStreams.uid = uid; // keep track of the stream uid  
      console.log('User ' + uid + ' joined channel successfully');
      $('#main_live_video').html('')
      $('#publishBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#publishBtn').text("Please Wait");
      $('#publishBtn').addClass('hidden');
      $('.end_vdo_call').removeClass('hidden');

      $.post(requestUrl + "?f=live", {stream_name: channelName}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    if (data.status == 200) {
                      $('#live_post_id').val(data.post_id);
                    }
                  });
  }, function(err) {
      console.log('[ERROR] : join channel failed', err);
  });
}
function generateToken() {
 return null; // TODO: add a token generation
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because you are attempting to use an AppID that has Token authentication enabled, but not passing a token when you join the channel.

To resolve this you would generally have three options:

1. Create a new project and generate a new AppID. Open the [Project Management tab within the Agora Console](https://console.agora.io/projects). Click the "Create" button in the upper left section of the screen. Within the dialog box, make sure to select the bottom option. [image]
2. Generate a temporary token (valid for 24hrs) on your project using the [Project Management tab within the Agora Console](https://console.agora.io/projects). follow these steps:

   - Select the Generate Temp Token Option 
     [image]
   - Enter the channel name and generate a token
     [image]
   - update the `generateToken` function with your token string, instead of returning null.

```
function generateToken() {
  return null; // add a token string here
}
```

3. Implement a token server and generate dynamic tokens. Further details check out:

   - [Agora Guide on token generation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/token?platform=All%20Platforms#deploy-a-token-generator)
   - [GitHub repo with the token server Code for PHP](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/php).
   - Add the PHP script to generate the token within the `generateToken` function to return your token string, instead of returning null.

```
function generateToken() {
  return null; // add a token string here
}
```

The second option would not work for your implementation because you are generating a channel name  using a user name and appending a random value. When generating a temp token you need to know the name of the channel.